# If all children has an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

I want to check if all children has an attribute set, and if so add 1 more element in fo:

```
<row>
  <entry attribute="true"></entry>
  <entry attribute="true"></entry>
  <entry attribute="true"></entry>
</row>
```

Example; if every entry element has attribute = true, then add an element.

```
<xsl:template match="row">
  <fo:table-row>
    <xsl:apply-template/>
  </fo:table-row>

  <xsl:if test=""><!-- What to write here? -->
    <fo:table-row/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You may be interested in a shorter and more efficient solution :)

Comment: The initial expression in my answer needed adjustment and it has now been done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
count(*[@attribute="true"]) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

**This could be a little bit more efficient, because no counting of all attributes is necessary** and the evaluation can stop immediately on finding the first child-element for which the condition `@attribute = 'true'` is `false()`.

```
  <xsl:if test="not(*[not(@attribute = 'true')])">
    <fo:table-row/> 
  </xsl:if>
```

**Explanation**:

This is another application of the *double negation* rule:

```
for every $x some property-y is true
```

is equivalent to:

```
there isn't any $z in $x such that for $z property-y is not true
```

Answer (score 2):

Or if you're using XPath 2.0 and you like to make your code readable

```
  <xsl:if test="every $a in * satisfies $a/@attribute='true'">
    <fo:table-row/> 
  </xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Francis says or something like

```
count(*[not(@attribute="true")])
```

Comment: I like this, but don't you need another `not()`? `not(count(*[not(@attribute="true")]))`

Comment: Depends on what you're checking for :) I'd use `=0` instead of not here, though. After all `count` is not exactly boolean.

Comment: I think I will go with the number 1. Thank you for your replies!

Comment: @FrancisAvila's answer is okay, otherwise I wouldn't vote for it ;-)